# No routes matched location "/admin/home"

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need redirect to page home with basename '\admin'.

Steps:

- I enter url http://localhost:8080
- app redirect to http://localhost:8080/admin/home

**Expected Behavior**

render home component

**Actual Behavior**

Component isn't render and error in console: No routes matched location "/admin/home"

I have such dependencies:

```
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.8.5",
    "history": "5.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "6.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "redux": "4.2.0",
    "redux-first-history": "5.1.1",
    "redux-saga": "1.2.1"
```

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { HistoryRouter } from "redux-first-history/rr6";

import App from "./App";
import { history, store } from "./store";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <HistoryRouter history={history}>
        <App />
      </HistoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

app.js

```
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./About";
import Home from "./Home";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

store.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createReduxHistoryContext } from "redux-first-history";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const {
  createReduxHistory,
  routerMiddleware,
  routerReducer
} = createReduxHistoryContext({
  history: createBrowserHistory(),
  basename: "/admin"
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: combineReducers({
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  middleware: [routerMiddleware]
});

export const history = createReduxHistory(store);
```

I have [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-smoke-vnr9f8)

Answer (score 1):

Provide a `basename` prop to the router.

```
import { HistoryRouter } from "redux-first-history/rr6";

...

<HistoryRouter history={history} basename="/admin">
  <App />
</HistoryRouter>
```

[image: Edit no-routes-matched-location-admin-home]

Comment: It helps if we open http://localhost:8080/admin/home link, but when I open just http://localhost:8080 I see in console 
<Router basename="/admin"> is not able to match the URL "/" because it does not start with the basename, so the <Router> won't render anything.

Comment: @AlexeiDelezhov The `basename` prop is supposed to match where you are hosting the app. So for example of you are hosing on `"www.yoursite.com/admin"` then all routes and links will work relative from there. Running a development build on localhost serves the app up on `"/"` though so you'll *always* need to manually navigate to `"/admin"` to get your routing/links to work as expected. It's the same idea on your host, if you only navigate manually to `"www.yoursite.com/"` then the page hosting the app isn't reached and the React app isn't loaded.

Comment: Yep, but in react-router v5 was this behaviour. I found [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8427), soulution works for me

Comment: @AlexeiDelezhov No, I don't believe the behavior was any different in RRDv5. The solution is to externally (*to the app*) redirect/navigate to the directory hosting the app, which is more or less exactly what I described. Glad this is working for you now though. Cheers.